# How to clean up masscan output (-oL)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, output

I have a problem with the output produced by the masscan utility with the -oL options ("grep-able" output); for instance, it outputs this:

```
Host: 143.137.155.7 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 177.105.21.41 ()  Ports: 8080/open/tcp////
Host: 187.78.236.98 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 177.137.76.220 () Ports: 8080/open/tcp////
Host: 177.105.10.112 () Ports: 9000/open/tcp////
Host: 191.232.34.9 ()   Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 179.55.65.144 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp////
Host: 177.83.203.147 () Ports: 8080/open/tcp////
Host: 177.182.50.124 () Ports: 8000/open/tcp////
```

The above is neither very readable nor easy to understand.

How can I use Linux command-line utilities, e.g. sed, awk, or grep, to output something as follows, using the file above?

```
143.137.155.7:80
177.105.21.41:8080
187.78.236.98:80
177.137.76.220:8080
177.105.10.112:9000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
sed 's/^Host: \([0-9.]*\).*Ports: \([0-9]*\).*$/\1:\2/g'
```

Explanation:

- `s/regex/replacement/` substitutes `regex` with `replacement`
- `^` matches the start of the string
- `Host:` matches itself
- `[0-9.]` is a character range that matches the digits 0 to 9 and `.`
- `[0-9.]*` matches zero or more digits/dots
- `\([0-9.]*\)` makes the matched IP address available in the replacement as `\1`
- `.` matches any single character
- `.*` matches zero or more single characters (i.e. any string)
- `Ports:` matches itself
- `\([0-9]*\)` matches a string of digits and makes it available as `\2`
- `.*$` matches the rest of the string

The flag `g` at the end applies the replacement to all matches rather than the first match on each line. In this case, there can only be one match (the entire line), so the flag doesn't do anything. I type it out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

awk can take regex as a delimiter. Split on either / or 1+ spaces and then print the columns.

```
awk -F '[/ ]+' '{print $2 ":" $5}'
```

Answer (score 1):

While Tom's answer is probably the best one for the job, it never hurts to have other options.

Using `awk` and `cut`:

```
awk 'OFS=":" {print $2,$5}' | cut -d/ -f-1
```

There is almost certainly a more efficient way to do this entirely in `awk` but I am not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk  -F'[ /]' '{print $2":"$(NF-6)}/9000/{exit}' file

143.137.155.7:80
177.105.21.41:8080
187.78.236.98:80
177.137.76.220:8080
177.105.10.112:9000
```

Comment: why there is a need for /9000/{exit}? I tried to just print $2 and $5 and it worked fine for me

Comment: @JayRajput The expected output in the question only has the first 5 lines. I think Claes understood it to be a requirement ("display only the lines up to the one with port 9000"), but it's more likely that the OP didn't bother to write the remaining lines.

Comment: In order to limit the output to 5 lines.

Comment: Thanks. Got it now.