# Cleaning up IP output on command line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, output

I have a problem with the output L options ("grep-able" output); for instance, it outputs this:

```
| 14.138.12.21:123   | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.184.122:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.179.27:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.20.65:123   | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.12.235:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.178.97:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.182.153:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.178.124:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.201.191:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.180.26:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.13.129:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
```

The above is neither very readable nor easy to understand.

How can I use Linux command-line utilities, e.g. sed, awk, or grep, to output something as follows, using the file above?

output

```
14.138.12.21
14.138.184.122
14.138.179.27
14.138.20.65
14.138.12.235
```

Comment: This is almost the exact same question you asked 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325397/how-to-clean-up-masscan-output-ol.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` with field separator as space, and `:` and getting the second field:

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{print $2}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
| 14.138.12.21:123   | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.184.122:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.179.27:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.20.65:123   | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.12.235:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.178.97:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.182.153:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.178.124:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.201.191:123 | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.180.26:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |
| 14.138.13.129:123  | unknown                   | disabled    |

% awk -F '[ :]' '{print $2}' file.txt
14.138.12.21
14.138.184.122
14.138.179.27
14.138.20.65
14.138.12.235
14.138.178.97
14.138.182.153
14.138.178.124
14.138.201.191
14.138.180.26
14.138.13.129
```

Answer (score 2):

AWK is perfect for cases when you want to split the file by "columns", and you know exactly that the order of values/columns is constant. AWK splits the lines by a field separator (which can be a regular expression like `'[: ]'`). The column names are accessible by their positions from the left: `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.:

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{print $2}' src.log
awk -F '[ :|]' '{print $3}' src.log
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ :|]"} {print $3}' src.log
```

You can also filter the lines with a regular expression:

```
awk -F '[ :]' '/138\.179\./ {print $2}' src.log
```

However, it is [impossible to capture substrings with the regular expression groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern).

SED is more flexible in regard to regular expressions:

```
sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9\.]+)\:.*/\1/' src.log
```

However, it lacks many useful features of the Perl-like regular expressions we used to use in every day programming. For example, even the extended syntax (`-r`) fails to interpret `\d` as a number.

Perhaps, Perl is the most flexible tool for parsing files. You can opt to simple expressions:

```
perl -n -e '/^\D*([^:]+):/ and print "$1\n"' src.log
```

or make the matching as strict as you like:

```
perl -n -e '/^\D*((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}):/ and print "$1\n"' src.log
```

Answer (score 1):

using sed

```
sed -r 's/^ *[|] *([0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+):[0-9]{3}.*/\1/
```